# Bluetooth headphones are connected but sound output is coming from the speakers

Tags: sound, headphones, connection

My bluetooth headphones are connected. It even shows that in sound settings, but sound output is coming from the speakers.

[image]

Comment: Normally when headphones are connected, speakers disconnect. Try to turn off headphoned or remove pairing.

Comment: I did try that, no progress yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VLC you need to tell it to change the output - Playback menu > Renderer, then pick.